# Yarn, node-gyp rebuild compile error, node_modules/fsevents: Command failed

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

I am using Yarn to handle the packages.

`yarn install` shows the error regardless of the package that I use but the install looked like it successfully finished and files are set under `node-modules` directly.(Somehow `jquery-ui` did not appear under `node-modules`)

I deleted `yarn.lock` and tried again, but in vain.

Can anyone help?

My environment is like this below:

```
whitebear$ yarn -v
1.10.1
whitebear$ node -v
v11.0.0
whitebear$ npm -v
6.4.1
```

package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.20.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
    "dev": "encore dev",
    "watch": "encore dev --watch",
    "build": "encore production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "encore": "^0.0.30-beta",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jquery.event.drag": "^2.2.2",
    "slickgrid-es6": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

log for yarn `install`

```
whitebearnoMacBook-puro:myinvestlist whitebear$ sudo yarn install
yarn install v1.10.1
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning " > sass-loader@7.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
warning "runway@3.15.47-beta" is missing a bundled dependency "favicon.json". This should be reported to the package maintainer.
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[1/4] ⠈ fsevents
[-/4] ⠈ waiting...
[3/4] ⠈ fsevents
warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myinvestlist/node_modules/encore/node_modules/fsevents: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-gyp rebuild
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myinvestlist/node_modules/encore/node_modules/fsevents
Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@11.0.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
gyp info spawn args [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.0.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myinvestlist/node_modules/encore/node_modules/fsevents/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.0.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/whitebear/.node-gyp/11.0.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/whitebear/.node-gyp/11.0.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.0.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/whitebear/.node-gyp/11.0.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myinvestlist/node_modules/encore/node_modules/fsevents',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:190:32: warning: 'BooleanValue' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      || optionsObj->Get(opt)->BooleanValue();
                               ^
/Users/whitebear/.node-gyp/11.0.0/include/node/v8.h:2568:3: note: 'BooleanValue' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATED(\"Use maybe version\", bool BooleanValue() const);
  ^
/Users/whitebear/.node-gyp/11.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:194:32: warning: 'BooleanValue' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      && optionsObj->Get(opt)->BooleanValue();
                               ^
/Users/whitebear/.node-gyp/11.0.0/include/node/v8.h:2568:3: note: 'BooleanValue' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATED(\"Use maybe version\", bool BooleanValue() const);
  ^
/Users/whitebear/.node-gyp/11.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:213:31: warning: 'Uint32Value' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      ? optionsObj->Get(opt)->Uint32Value()
                              ^
/Users/whitebear/.node-gyp/11.0.0/include/node/v8.h:2571:3: note: 'Uint32Value' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATED(\"Use maybe version\", uint32_t Uint32Value() const);
  ^
/Users/whitebear/.node-gyp/11.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATED'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:339:13: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    return  _NAN_ERROR(v8::Exception::Error, errmsg);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:343:5: error: no member named 'ThrowException' in namespace 'v8'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::Error, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:324:11: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \\\n      ~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:343:5: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::Error, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:324:26: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \\\n                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:348:9: error: no type named 'ThrowException' in namespace 'v8'
    v8::ThrowException(error);
    ~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:355:65: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    v8::Local<v8::Value> err = v8::Exception::Error(v8::String::New(msg));
                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:356:50: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
    v8::Local<v8::Object> obj = err.As<v8::Object>();
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:356:52: error: expected expression
    v8::Local<v8::Object> obj = err.As<v8::Object>();
                                                   ^
../../nan/nan.h:357:65: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 1
    obj->Set(v8::String::New(\"code\"), v8::Int32::New(errorNumber));
                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~            ^
/Users/whitebear/.node-gyp/11.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3154:3: note: 'New' declared here
  static Local<Integer> New(Isolate* isolate, int32_t value);
  ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:357:26: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    obj->Set(v8::String::New(\"code\"), v8::Int32::New(errorNumber));
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:369:12: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    return _NAN_ERROR(v8::Exception::TypeError, errmsg);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:373:5: error: no member named 'ThrowException' in namespace 'v8'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::TypeError, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:324:11: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \\\n      ~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:373:5: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::TypeError, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:324:26: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \\\n                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:377:12: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    return _NAN_ERROR(v8::Exception::RangeError, errmsg);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:381:5: error: no member named 'ThrowException' in namespace 'v8'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::RangeError, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:324:11: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \\\n      ~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:381:5: error: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String'
    _NAN_THROW_ERROR(v8::Exception::RangeError, errmsg);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:324:26: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_THROW_ERROR'
      v8::ThrowException(_NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg));                             \\\n                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:319:50: note: expanded from macro '_NAN_ERROR'
# define _NAN_ERROR(fun, errmsg) fun(v8::String::New(errmsg))
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:406:13: error: no member named 'smalloc' in namespace 'node'
    , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
      ~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan.h:141:71: note: expanded from macro 'NAN_INLINE'
# define NAN_INLINE(declarator) inline __attribute__((always_inline)) declarator
                                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan.h:416:12: error: no matching function for call to 'New'
    return node::Buffer::New(data, size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/whitebear/.node-gyp/11.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:49:40: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char *' to 'v8::Isolate *' for 1st argument
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate, size_t length);
                                       ^
/Users/whitebear/.node-gyp/11.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:52:40: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char *' to 'v8::Isolate *' for 1st argument
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/whitebear/.node-gyp/11.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:64:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/whitebear/.node-gyp/11.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:57:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 5 arguments, but 2 were provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:420:12: error: no matching function for call to 'New'
    return node::Buffer::New(size);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/whitebear/.node-gyp/11.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:49:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate, size_t length);
                                       ^
/Users/whitebear/.node-gyp/11.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:52:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires at least 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/whitebear/.node-gyp/11.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:64:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 1 was provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
/Users/whitebear/.node-gyp/11.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:57:40: note: candidate function not viable: requires 5 arguments, but 1 was provided
NODE_EXTERN v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> New(v8::Isolate* isolate,
                                       ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:427:26: error: no member named 'Use' in namespace 'node::Buffer'
    return node::Buffer::Use(data, size);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
3 warnings and 20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.0.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command \"/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.0.0/bin/node\" \"/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.0.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js\" \"rebuild\"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/myinvestlist/node_modules/encore/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v11.0.0
✨  Done in 87.84s.
```

Comment: did you solve this? and how?

Answer (score 41):

I just ran into something similar. deleting `node_modules` and removing `yarn.lock` fixed the problem for me.

`sudo rm -r node_modules && rm yarn.lock && yarn install`

Not sure if it was getting caught up on some conflicts.

Comment: "Dependencies are hard mk." I hate to be the one suggesting this too but yes clearing out stale node modules does work `sudo rm -r node_modules && rm yarn.lock && yarn install` I still caution anyone please remember `sudo rm -r` anything is elevated privileges and recursive, a mistype can lead to deleting a lot of work that might not be recoverable without a version management system like `git`.

Comment: I tried same thing but doesn't work for me as i was trying it for upgrading my project.

Answer (score 14):

`yarn upgrade` did the trick for me, see https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5962

Comment: This is the way!

Comment: not works for me

Answer (score 10):

Add this to your `package.json` file, then re-run yarn (or yarn install):

```
"resolutions": {
  "**/**/fsevents": "^1.2.9"
}
```

source : https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5962#issuecomment-491934806

Comment: I would probably go for `^2.3.3` now.

Answer (score 3):

I downgraded the `node` version to `v8.16.0`. You could use `n` for this. It worked for me.

Make sure you remove previous versions before that.

```
brew uninstall node
```

Install downgraded version

```
brew install n
n 8.16.0
```

If it doesn't work though, try downgrading/upgrading your node versions.

Comment: Why version 8.16.0? What changed after this version?

Comment: This is the version that worked for me. But, looking into everyone's answers I think the problem could occur because of the node/yarn version compatibility with the packages that are already in place. so I will edit my answer

Comment:  this is a huge overkill

Comment: elaborate @stkvtflw

Comment: overkill mainly because you need to reinstall node again. Not the best approach, but if it solves the problem. Curious if changing node version with nvm solves the issue

Comment: Not sure this a wise answer, anything v16 and below is no longer being maintained.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have all the tools listed here for your OS? https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation

Answer (score 0):

downgrading to node 12 LTS version worked for me.
I used [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) for this.